# How can you merge objects in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm looking for the best solution to merge all objects in one array

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
 {name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz'}, {name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example'}
];
```

I want to achieve: `{name: ['Fred', 'Anne'], surname: ['Example', 'Shultz']}`

What's the best option for that (es6)? Maybe I can do something like that using lodash? Which helpers should I use?

Comment: is every object in `arrayOfObjects` guaranteed to have the same properties?

Comment: @Rafonix You should accept the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/#mergeWith) like so:

```
const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...arrayOfObjects, (value, objValue) =>
    (value || []).concat(objValue)
);
```

**Example:**

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz'}, {name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example'}
];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...arrayOfObjects, (value, objValue) =>
    (value || []).concat(objValue)
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

You could reduce the array by iterating the entries and collecting the values, depending of the keys.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz' }, { name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

easy with lodash:

```
grouped = _.mapValues(arrayOfObjects[0], 
    (val, key) => _.map(arrayOfObjects, key))
```

pure es6

```
let grouped = {};

for (let obj of arrayOfObjects)
    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj))
        grouped[key] = (grouped[key] || []).concat(val)
```

if the keys differ from item to item, you could use something like this to collect them all:

```
grouped = _(arrayOfObjects)
    .flatMap(_.entries)
    .groupBy(0)
    .mapValues(x => _.map(x, 1))
    .value()
```

Comment: I liked the lodash approach but it is not generic enough. It will break if any objects past the first one have different properties. e.g. `{name: 'John', city: 'Miami'}`

Comment: Look at https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/tp70frm5/627/. You will see in the console that first you have an `undefined` as last element in the `surname` and 2nd you have no property for `city` since you did `mapValues` on the first object and not on `every` in the array.

Comment: @Akrion: yep, I see, fixed!

Comment: @georg isn't the fixed lodash version exactly look like my answer?

Answer (score 7):

You could do it like this:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz'}, {name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example'}
];

const result = {};
arrayOfObjects.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = [];
    }
    result[key].push(item[key]);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Short way with array reduce:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
 {name: "name1", surname: "surname1"}, {name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example'}, {name: 'name3', surname: 'Example3'}
];
/*
{name: ['Fred', 'Anne'], surname: ['Example', 'Shultz']}
*/
var result = arrayOfObjects.reduce((obj,current)=>{
    (obj['name'] = obj['name']||[]).push(current.name);
    (obj['surname'] = obj['surname']||[]).push(current.surname);
    return obj;
},{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't make it any more complicated than it needs to be:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz'},
    {name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example'}
];

const result = {name:[], surname:[]};
for (const obj of arrayOfObjects)
    for (const prop in result)
        result[prop].push(obj[prop]);
```

I will assume that you statically know the property names that your result should have - one can't really do it dynamically anyway as that wouldn't work properly for an empty input array.

Comment: You can't use for..of on an object, you should use for..in instead, or iterate over `Object.keys(result)`.

Comment: @Frax Oops, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lodash approach

```
  _(input).flatMap(_.entries).groupBy(0).mapValues(v => _.map(v, 1)).value()
```

```js
var input = [
 {name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz'}, {name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example'}
];

var res =   _(input).flatMap(_.entries).groupBy(0).mapValues(v => _.map(v, 1)).value()

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This will take care if the objects doesn't have exactly same key sets

Comment: This results in a slightly different output structure than expected.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 see edit, I forget to map it to the expected type of result

Answer (score 2):

If the `arrayOfObjects` is set on these 2 props then it is as simple as:

```js
const data = [{ name: 'Fred', surname: 'Shultz' }, { name: 'Anne', surname: 'Example' }]

const r = data.reduce((r,c) => 
   (r.name.push(c.name), r.surname.push(c.surname),r), {name:[], surname:[]})

console.log(r)
```

One `reduce` with an accumulator of `{name:[], surname:[]}` to be filled.

If you need to be more generic and work for `any set of objects`:

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'Fred',
  surname: 'Shultz'
},{
  name: 'Anne',
  surname: 'Example' 
},{
  name: 'John',
  position: 'Dev' // <--- Notice different prop
}]

const result = data.reduce((r,c) => 
  (Object.keys(c).map(k => r[k] = [...r[k] || [], c[k]]), r), {})

console.log(result)
```

Again is just a `reduce` with `Object.keys` to do the job.

Note both approaches utilize ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [array destricturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and (for the 2nd one) combining multiple operations via enclosing them in parentheses `(op1,op2)`

Answer (score 1):

This is one abroach of implementation details, written in fairly easy to understand and readable manner.

https://codesandbox.io/s/r7x16j950n

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { name: "Fred", surname: "Shultz" },
  { name: "Anne", surname: "Example" }
];

let obj = {};

arrayOfObjects.forEach(row => {
  Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = !obj[key]
      ? [row[key]]
      : [...obj[key], row[key]];
  });
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work - uses a few ES6 helpers, but the key is `Array#reduce` which is in ES5.

```
const result = arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (key in acc) {
            acc[key].push(obj[key]);
        }
        else {
            acc[key] = [obj[key]];
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any library

```
const mergeObjectInArray=(input)=>{
const myObj={};
Object.keys(input[0]).forEach(key=>myObj[key]=input.map(inp=>inp[key]));
return myObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> with pure `javascript`

```js
var myInput = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6 }, { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 }];
    var myArray = [];
    var myObject = {};
    function isArray(a){
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Array]' ;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < myInput.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myInput[i]) {
            if (myInput[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (myArray.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    myArray.push(key);
                    myObject[key] = myInput[i][key];
                } else {
                    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        newary = [];
                        if (isArray(myObject[key])) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < myObject[key].length; i++) {
                                newary.push(myObject[key][i]);
                            }
                        } else {
                            newary.push(myObject[key]);
                        }
                        newary.push(myInput[i][key]);
                        myObject[key] = newary;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(myObject);
```